# Django & Google-mobwrite - Form ids

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, collaborative-editing

I use the [google-mobwrite](https://code.google.com/p/google-mobwrite/) code, trying to make a collaborative form in a Django application...

I use:

```
<SCRIPT SRC="http://mobwrite3.appspot.com/static/compressed_form.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
  mobwrite.syncGateway = 'http://mobwrite3.appspot.com/scripts/q.py';
</SCRIPT>
<BODY ONLOAD="mobwrite.share('id_fieldA');">
```

And it works without any problems, in my application, I have the following model:

```
ModelA
   nameA
   fieldA
```

Let's say I have a dynamic unknwon number of different objects from this model:

```
object1 and object2 and ...
```

The problem is that the id generated in the template by the form for the `fieldA` attribute is always the same:

```
id_fieldA
```

On the website Neil Fraser says:

> Note that MobWrite has no authentication. That's the job of the host application. MobWrite is simply a sharing pipe that the host application uses to connect forms with each other. To keep unwanted users out and to prevent collisions, it is recommended to use form element IDs that are eight-character random strings. If all users of a form are to be globally connected (as in the demos), then one can just hard-code random IDs. If the users are to be broken into groups, with data only syncing between members of the group, then the IDs must be generated so that members of the group all have the same IDs.

I would like to have a different `fieldA` id for each object, unpredictable by a member of the object or a member of another object. But the id of the field has to be the same for all the members of a same object...I have no idea about what to do to achieve that..